# Q My website is really slow. Im using wordpress with elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm trying to make my website [gambletopics](https://www.gambletopics.com).
It's created with WordPress and built with elementor.
If I check on gtmatrix my website is really slow.
I have already removed my images to watch if there is an improvement.
unfortunately without result.

I put a lot of effort in my website.
But nobody wants to open a slow speed website.

I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: It's not only images that contribute to a slow website. You can use this link to check on other factors https://www.wpbeginner.com/wordpress-performance-speed/

Answer (score 0):

Try installing and configuring plugins:

- WP Super Cache - https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/
- reSmush.it Image Optimizer - https://wordpress.org/plugins/resmushit-image-optimizer/
- Hummingbird – Speed Optimize, Cache, Minify & Defer Critical CSS/Javascript -https://wordpress.org/plugins/hummingbird-performance/

Also, try deploying Cloudflare(https://www.cloudflare.com/)

You can find all the instructions for plugins and Cloudflare on google.

I hope this helps

Best,
Kaz